# Find which rows are causing Foreign Key Constraint Failure Error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreign-keys

I am getting the following error when i try and insert something into my database:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

(`database_name`.`catalog_category_entity_varchar`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_VCHR_ENTT_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_i)'
```

Am i right in thinking this means:

there is an `entity_i` in `catalog_category_entity` that is not found in
`entity_id` in `catalog_category_entity_varchar`

Is there an SQL query i can do on the database that can find what is causing this?

The database is Magentos and this error comes up simply when i create a category programmatically:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$category->setName($design);
$category->setPath($path);
$category->save();
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question, but these are some horribly confusing table and field names...

Comment: Can you provide the database schema (`show create table catalog_category_entity` and `show create table catalog_category_entity_varchar`), and the query you're running when this error occurs?

Comment: @RoelHarbers I agree, sadly it is a magento store so i have no control on these. Pundit - I can reindex the db through magento's reindex

Comment: @RoelHarbers just included the query in my question and here is the structure of the magento databases: https://inchoo.net/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/magento_v116-database_diagram.pdf

Comment: I'm not familiar with Magento, so I don't know how your code maps to sql (a quick google search suggests it's not as straight-forward as one would think). Is there a way to let Magento log the actual sql it's doing?